# Battleship array check

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a battleship game and I am having an issue with shooting at the same location.  I have a single array for the shoot method, holding in `shoot[0]` for the rows and `shoot[1]` for the columns.  I am trying to create a 2d array to store the location of `shoot[0]` for the rows and the `shoot[1]` for the columns; then with that double array I am able to check already hit location.  The thing is that, I am not sure if you can store signals array in the location in the double array[row][col].

After working on this code for a while, I have got the 2D array to store the values of the Shoot[0] and shoot[1].  But I do not know if i am doing it correctly:

```
    public static void shoot(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){
    int[][] check = new int[6][6];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter AI Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter AI Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();

    while((shoot[0] <= 0 || shoot[1] <= 0) ||(shoot[0] == 0 && shoot[1] == 0) || (shoot[0] > 5 || shoot[1] > 5)){
      System.out.println("You must enter a location greater than 0 and NOT over 5! ");
      System.out.print("Enter Row: ");
      shoot[0] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter Column: ");
      shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    }    

    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 25; row++){
      for (int col = 0; col < 25; col++){
        if (row == shoot[0] && col == shoot[1])
        {
          check[row][0] = shoot[0];
          check[row][col] = shoot[1];
          temp1 = row;
          temp2 = col;
        }
      }
    }

    if (check[temp1][0] == ships[temp1][0] && check[temp1][temp2] == ships[temp1][temp2])
    {
      System.out.print("You have already entered that location!");
    }

    shoot[0]--;
    shoot[1]--;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but I'll try to answer as best I can. There's no need for the for loop to check every position of shoot because you already have the coordinates. I'm not sure of the dimensions of your ships array but you can directly access the variable with the coordinates entered in by the user. You could do something like:

```
int beenShot = 1; //keep in mind these are arbitrary values
int notShot = 0; //I don't know how you are tracking if a shot has been fired there or not
if (ships[shoot[0]][shoot[1]] == beenShot)
{
  System.out.println("You have already entered that location!")
}
```

Also, as a side note, the

```
(shoot[0] == 0 && shoot[1] == 0)
```

part of the first conditional is not needed because the first condition already accounts for both being zero (because you're checking if either is 0 when you check:

```
(shoot[0] <= 0 || shoot[1] <= 0)
```

Anyways, hope this helped.